# Generate custom unique key in asp.net dynamic data

Tags: c#, asp.net, scaffolding, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am new to ASP.net dynamic data. I have a column in database (tracking ID) it requires to be generated in a pattern through code i.e "23041401" (the date and a 2 digit increment number). I have tried lot of things but need guidance to go in the right way. I have made a separate class for my "cases" table for setting the metadata etc.

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for formatting
/// </summary>

[ScaffoldTable(true)]
[DisplayName("Cases")]
[MetadataType(typeof(caseMetadata))]

public partial class @case 
{


}

public class caseMetadata
{
    [UIHint("datetelerik")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    public object s_date { get; set; }

    [UIHint("datetelerik")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("End Date")]
    public object e_date { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Multilinetext")]
    [DisplayName("Case Description")]
    public object case_desc { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Amount")]
    public object amount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Invoices")]
    public object invoices { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Logs")]
    public object cases_logs { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [DisplayName("Tracking ID")]
    public object tracking_id {get; set;}

}
```

Here's the function I have so far for generating the ID.

```
public string GenerateId()
        {
        int case_id = 1;
        int t_id;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hafee‌​z_enterprisesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open(); SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(case_id) as max from cases", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
            {
            case_id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["max"].ToString());
            }
        t_id = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + (case_id + 1));
        return t_id.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I was trying to do this through custom pages but not succeeded :(

Comment: I mean, what have you tried so far to generate the ID? Please provide the function you're using, or at least take a stab at writing one.

Comment: int case_id = 1;
int t_id;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hafeez_enterprisesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(case_id) as max from cases", con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
case_id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["max"].ToString());
}
t_id = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + (case_id + 1));
Label1.Text = t_id.ToString();

Comment: Mason thanks for your support. With my basic coding skills, I would be using above code to generate the ID :) Would be much appreciated if you may suggest better way and better code

Comment: I have pasted your code in the question. Please avoid putting long bits of code in comments, as it makes the comments hard to read. Long bits of code belong in questions or answers. And you should have included what you tried in the first place.

Comment: Your update code looks fine for generating an ID. Is it working? Then this question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Critiques of code would be a better topic for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok Mason thanks. By the way the code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is almost always a bad way of doing a database key.  It requires a trip to the database to get a key, and in high-volume cases, you could still wind up with duplicates if two requests happen at the same time.   It's usually best to use a natural key or an auto-increment if possible.

That said, if you don't have control over that, or it would be too difficult to refactor, and have to use this technique, then one way would be to intercept the object in the data context before it gets saved. You can loop through all changes and do "stuff" before the database calls are made.  I've used this to set changed date, track the user, or log. Something like this might work in your case:

```
public class YourDbContext{

public override int SaveChanges()
{
     foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
     {
            var caseEntry = entry.Entity as @case;
            if (caseEntry != null)
            {

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    caseEntry.Id = GenerateId();                       
                }

            }
     }
     return base.SaveChanges();
}

}
```

I believe this would work with your dynamic data code (assuming you're using Entity Framework).

Comment: I am using Linq to SQL

Comment: I was aware that making a database trip for getting information to perform insert, update & delete is not a good practice. After reading your answer, I explore sql database and finally did this by using triggers in sql database. Thank you so much for your expert response and guidance and allowing me move things further in the right way.